# Lost RDP access to VM azure after firewall changes

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, azure, rdp

I have an Azure virtual machine running Windows Server 2012.

Mistakenly changed the windows firewall setting to Block all incoming connection including those in the allowed list

[image]

Now i am unable to take the RDP of the VM. so i can't reverse the option also

I tried reset the RDP configuration from the Azure portal but that also did not help..

How can i revert the change to take RDP of the VM now..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way to do this is as follows.

1) Turn off the current VM (Call this VM1)

2) Spin Up a new VM (Call this VM2) and attach the OS disk from VM1 as a data disk. See [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-attach-disk/) question for reference.

3) Boot VM2 and open registry

4) Load the registry hive from the attached OS disk of VM1. See [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/21788/how-to-edit-registry-hives-without-live-running) question for reference

5) Disable the firewall by looking for the following key `EnableFirewall` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy` See [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/371222/disabling-windows-server-2008-firewall) question for reference

6) Unload the registry hive.

7) Turn off VM2 and remove the attach disk

8) Boot VM1 access via RDP

Comment: You saved me man...Worked like a charm!!!!! i tried this approach but not able to get pass the step 4..cant find how to edit the registry..anyways thanks a ton...

Answer (score 2):

This might help someone.

1. Login to your Azure Dashboard
2. Locate Resources and click on the VM
3. Click on `Run Command` [See Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GvgL.png)
4. click on the first Command listed (Honestly clicking any other does not matter) [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpdIn.png)
5. Type in `Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain,Public,Private -Enabled False` in the command box and click run [Sample Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH4oi.png)
6. Please note, the above command disables the firewall completely, it is totally your responsibility to re-nable it after you gain access to your server again

Answer (score 1):

- Easiest way

On Azure portal,

Run Command => SetRDPPort command

Set port as 3389 and clcik on 'Run'.

[RDP Port 3389 enable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YKTu.jpg)